# Where do you find the ApplicationId to pass to TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication(string) for a background task

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to update a live tile from a background task (and the lock screen badge, and show toast notifications).  I've got code that works when the app is running, and it runs through to completion as a background task, but nothing happens to the live tile/toast/badge.  I'm assuming that's because I need to use the overload of `TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication()` that takes a string, but I don't know where to find the string and/or what the format is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Package relative app identifier (PRAID)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.id.aspx)

Edit per comment:  Have you tried the Application ID that you specify in the Manifest or the ID you use to create the Secondary Tile?

Comment: Hmm, that value seems to be the same between the main app and the background task.  It's accepted (no exception is thrown), but seems to have no effect on the Tile/Toast/Badge.

Comment: Nevermind. With the addition of more logging, it looks like my code isn't working, and explicitly clears the tile/toast/badge :(